# Why would someone use echo to assign values to variables in bash or ksh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

Recently I came across an unusual use of echo to assign variables in a client's ksh scripts.

For example, there are many instances such as the following

```
a='something'
b='else'
c=`echo "${a} ${b}"`
```

I have been unable to come up with any reason why someone may have done this.

Could there be some legacy reason for this?
(I've been doing shell for 30+ years, and never before have I seen this)

Or is it just ignorance?

Comment: Their ignorance on how shell scripting works? Probably.

Comment: Maybe legacy? They previously did something else that made sense for backticks to be used and then made the minimal change possible when that changed?

Comment: Interesting. I can come up with many reasons for printf, but none for echo on the top of my head.

Comment: Shell script has the unfortunate honor of being used by many people who never wanted to or were given an opportunity (or were unable) to learn it.  You see all kinds of beginner / ignorant antipatterns even in big production scripts from major companies.

Answer (score 3):

There is no compelling reason whatsoever for this, either in current bash, or its POSIX sh or Bourne predecessors.

```
c="$a $b"
```

...is a complete replacement for the code given, and runs far faster (try putting it in a loop; command substitutions, as created by backticks, fork off a new shell as a subprocess and read its stdout -- a high-overhead operation).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am in the midst of a cleanup of these scripts.
The superfluous echo's are being removed, and backticks are being converted to $().
Also removing 'useless use of cat', which is also abundant.

Answer (score 0):

What you saw is an example of bad use of echo because c could be declared as:

```
c="$a $b"
```

A common use of echo is when you need comands to filter output, for example

```
$ line="100090 $100,00 Mary"
$ name=`echo "$line" | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z]+$"`
echo $name
Mary
```

But it would be more efficient if you don't use echo at all. The same thing above can be done with "read", without creating a new process:

```
$ line="100090 $100,00 Paul"
$ read -r _ _ name _ <<<"$line"
echo $name
Paul
```

Comment: That's not actually a good example at all: It string-splits and glob-expands the contents of `$line`. Thus, if you had a column that contained `*`, it would be replaced with a list of filenames; if you had tabs between your columns they would become spaces; etc.

Comment: Moreover, it's **much** more efficient to simply ask bash to give you the third row in your line than to launch an external tool to extract it. `awk` makes sense if you're using a single awk process to handle a whole string -- not for one-line-at-a-time operations.

Comment: $name is the third field of the string, not the third line

Comment: I said "third row in your line", I didn't say "third line". "Column" or "field" would indeed have been more accurate, though.

Comment: Anyway, that should show why you would use echo in a variable assignment.

Comment: And as I said above, it's a **buggy** way to do an assignment, on account of glob-expanding and string-splitting content. `read -r _ _ name _ <<<"$line"` is a cleaner alternative, which doesn't require any subprocesses to be invoked whatsoever and can be used to split out several fields at once (`read -r time employer name _`).

Comment: ...if you made it `echo "$line" | awk [...]`, with the quotes, you'd at least reduce that somewhat -- though you'd still have undefined behavior with any input containing backslashes (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html for the full set of cases where `echo` implementations are allowed to do whatever they want).

Comment: changed the example.

Comment: Consider `grep -E` rather than `grep -P` when possible -- the latter is only available on GNU releases compiled with non-default options, whereas the former is specified by POSIX and guaranteed to be everywhere.

Comment: Also, in modern bash, one can do similar [and again more efficiently] with `[[ $line =~ [[:alpha:]]+$ ]]`, and then inspecting the `$BASH_REMATCH` value.

Comment: ...and do still add quotes, `echo "$line"`, not `echo $line`, or you still have bugs with wildcards.

Comment: grep -E won't return ONLY the matched string, while grep -Po does

Comment: ...but `grep -Eo` will. You still don't need the `-P` -- older GNU greps or those compiled without libpcre will have `-o` but not `-P`, so even for a command only intended to run on GNU platforms, `-E` is still more portable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114145/discussion-between-bruno-negrao-zica-and-charles-duffy).